# How do I save a variable read in a function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, save

Let's say I have this function:

```
void read() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

and I want to use the num variable in another function like this:

```
void func() {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

But when trying to compile it says the variable is uninitialized. I know that it most likely requires pointers, but I can't get a hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about doing this:

- Return the variable that you read to a caller, or
- Have the caller provide space for your variable, and store it there.

The first approach requires you to change the return type to `int`:

```
int read() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    return num;
}

void func() {
    int num = read();
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

The second approach requires you to take an `int*` pointer:

```
void read(int* p) {
    scanf("%d", p);
}

void func() {
    int num;
    read(&num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Comment: There's a third way: Call whoever needs that data from your function. Though that does not really scale.

Comment: I should've mentioned that the read() function also has some {printf}'s so if I run read(&num) it will fill up with useless prints.

Comment: @AntiDeeagle `read()` is your function, so it is entirely up to you to make it print or not print whatever you like. If you need a version with no `printf`s, make a version with no `printf`s, and call it from the one with `printf`s.

Answer (score 1):

You `func` should be,

```
void func(int num) {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

And you also need to pass value like,

```
void read() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    func(num);
}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that the read() function also has some {printf}'s so if I run read(&num) it will fill up with useless prints.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable global and inside the function:

```
void func() {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Comment: This may not be the most scalable approach.

Comment: Avoid `static` and `thread_local` data; plan for re-use and concurrency with re-entrancy where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need pointers - you can simply return the value and then use it.

```
int read() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    return num;
}
```

You can now store the value returned from the function for future sue, e.g.

```
void func() {
    int num = read();
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that the read() function also has some {printf}'s so if I run read(&num) it will fill up with useless prints.

Comment: Perhaps the printing should be configurable - having a "read" function also write things isn't intuitive since it does more than one thing. Can you try carving it up differently.